# html/javascript: templating options in regular html

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, templating, client-side-templating

Converting a project from django into a flask API backend + backbone.js frontend

It was nice to be able to do `{% include %}` options in the HTML in order to make it more modular, i.e. I was able to separate out a discrete navbar.html, base.html, etc.

Is there an easy way to recreate this same structure in the absence of a web framework and if I am just building a frontend in HTML / JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of options, try searching. I usually go with [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: hmm, but I'd need to have a local flask instance to use something like this, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking for something pretty lightweight, you could try this https://github.com/psychobunny/dcp.templates

It was modelled after PHP templating engines like Smarty / phpBB's, but without much complexity... great for abstracting template files.

Otherwise like Joseph said, Handlebars is the way to go!